# Call global function from within Delphi class's method

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to call global methods from within a class where they are obscured by member functions of the same name?

I know in C++ you have the following syntax:

```
int var = 0;

void temp() {
    int var = 2;
    ::var = var;
} //Global var is set to 2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can by using the name of the unit instead of ::

Like:

```
unit1.var := 2;
```

See for more details:
http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/l/aa060899.htm

Comment: This is why I take issue with the use of the term "Global" in Delphi/Pascal.  i.e. not Global variables, but Unit variables.  If correct terminology were used then the answers to such questions would be more obvious.  i.e. not "how do I refer to a global variable?", but "How do I refer to a unit variable?".  The fact that "Uses" brings Unit symbols into scope is not sufficient reason to misuse the meaning of "Global" in a language that technically has no such concept (and the fact that the official help/documentation mis-uses the term too is no excuse either).

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
UnitName.VarName := 2
```